# Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin^{n}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})}{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^n} = e^{-\frac{x^2}{6}} $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I am wondering about a limit that wolframalpha got me and that you can find here [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%2Fsqrt%28n%29*a%29%5E%28n%29%2F%28a*x%2Fsqrt%28n%29%29%5En%20for%20n%20approaching%20infinity)

It says that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin^{n}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})}{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^n} = e^{-\frac{x^2}{6}} $$

Does anybody know if there is a "easy" way to get this?

Comment: You know that $\sin t = t - \frac{t^3}{6} + O(t^5)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer yep, got it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As
$$
1 - \frac{\sin t}t \sim_{t\to 0} \frac{t^2}{3!}
\\
\log (1+\epsilon) \sim_{\epsilon\to 0} \epsilon
$$

you have
$$
\frac{\sin^{n}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})}{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^n}
= \exp \left[
n\log \frac{\sin \frac x{\sqrt n}}{\frac x{\sqrt n}}
\right]
\to \exp \left[
n\left( -\frac 16 \left(\frac x{\sqrt n}\right)^2 \right)
\right]
= \exp\left( -\frac{x^2}6\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

If you know that $$\sin x =x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots,$$

then it will be helpful for you.